# Access Form - how do I only display fields and cell values if the cell has data?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Could someone please help me with configuring my access database? I would like to use a combo-box at the top of the form where the user selects from the available work forms (Column 1 in Table) and then it displays who is involved in the form. Currently it displays every field and to reduce to the information displayed I would like it to only display information if the cell has a value in it.

Am I using the wrong tool? Should I be using a Report instead? How's my table data, too much?

Many Thanks

[My current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1nX5.png)

[My wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMvOF.png)

Comment: If you just want to display the fields that have data, that can be done easily with a little VBA - but it looks like you also want to move them up in position which is not likely to work in a form - even with the CanShrink property set to True. If you're okay with just showing the filled fields I can provide some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I normally hide empty fields is to change the label for a field to a control and set the control source to the following:

```
=IIf([FieldName]<>'', "My label:", Null)
```

Then I set the CanShrink property on both the "label" and the field to Yes.

Finally I make sure the section it's in (typically the detail but you may have reason to use something other) also has CanShrink set to Yes.

When you stack the controls on top of each other in this manner you should get the result as you posted.

Note: this only works for reports or if you print the results of a form.  If you do not intend to allow entry of data into the form it would be better served as a report.